# Issue with split function

Tags: python

I have a list variable `name`:

```
name = ['Ny-site-1-145237890-service']
```

I want to split this list in a way so I can get `name = ['Ny-site-1']`.
To do this I am using the below code:

```
import re
name = ['Ny-site-1-145237890-service']
site_name = re.split('(-[0-9]-service)')[0]
```

But the above code is not give me the output I am looking for. How do I get the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) requires *2 arguments*, you are providing a single one.

Also, you need to add `+` quantifier (means "1 or more") for the `[0-9]` set of characters:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> name = ['Ny-site-1-145237890-service']
>>> re.split(r'-[0-9]+-service', name[0])[0]
'Ny-site-1'
```

I would also add the `maxsplit=1` argument to avoid unnecessary splits:

```
>>> re.split(r'-[0-9]+-service', name[0], maxsplit=1)[0]
'Ny-site-1'
```

---

You may also add an *end of a string check* to make the expression more reliable:

```
-[0-9]+-service$
```

And, you can also solve it with [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> re.sub(r'-[0-9]+-service$', '', name[0])
'Ny-site-1'
```

Comment: @ alecxe Thanks for your suggestions! In re.split I passed 2 arguments but forgot to mention in question. it was typo. But Thanks for correction!

Comment: @dharpatel okay, please see if the answer deserves to be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `+` in your regex to match multiple numbers.

```
name = 'Ny-site-1-145237890-service'
site_name = re.split('(-[0-9]+-service)', name)[0]
```

If you want to use an array to store your name(s), you can use

```
name = ['Ny-site-1-145237890-service']
site_name = re.split('(-[0-9]+-service)', name[0])[0]
```

If you have multiple names and you want to print them all, you can use

```
for i in names:
    print(re.split('(-[0-9]+-service)', i)[0])
```

Comment: @ intboolstring for your suggestions!